# SQL Update not working, not sure why

Tags: c#, sql-update

I have the following code that just will not update a record.  The data in question is being displayed in a DataGridView so I know that I am connecting to the database with no problem.  If anyone sees anything wrong with this can they please let me know, I've been eyeballing it for quite awhile and I can't see anything that doesn't look right.  There is no exception thrown it just, does nothing.  Thanks in advance.

```
    string strSQLConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\dbase.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
        string strUpdateCommand = "UPDATE table1 SET Active = @Active WHERE Order = @Order";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strSQLConnectionString);
        SqlCommand updateCommand = new SqlCommand(strUpdateCommand, connection);
                    connection.Open();
                    updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Order", "1");
                    updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Active", "True");
                    updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connection.Close();
                    updateCommand.Parameters.Clear();
```

In the real code there's a try/catch starting with the connection.open and ending with the parameters.clear.
Thanks again for any help on this.
erik

EDIT
@Rahul Singh Thanks for the reply, and the link to the blog.  The change you suggested with adding the missing '@' did not fix the problem.  Instead, what I am now getting is a 'connection is not open, connection must be open' exception on the executenonquery line.  I took your suggestion about the using blocks (thanks!) and the revised code is

```
                    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strSQLConnectionString))
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand updateCommand = new SqlCommand(strUpdateCommand, connection))
                        {
                            updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Order", "1");
                            updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Active", "True");
                            updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
```

What is odd is that if I explicitly say 'connection.open()' and 'connection.close();' then I don't get this error but, again, nothing gets done.  Thanks for any further help on this, I'm about to rub a hole in my scalp from all the head-scratching on this one.

Comment: You need to still open the connection. Please add `connection.open()` as the first line inside `using` block of SqlCommand, there is no need to close the connection though.

Comment: Ok, I did so, but now we're back to the 'nothing gets done' to the table.  I even stripped out the parameters and just did a straight up Update (i.e. "update table1 set active = 'true' where order = '1'";) and nothing happened - not even an exception.
I'm starting to wonder if I am indeed not connected somehow to the database.  The field names are right, I'm using the same connection string to populate the datagridview as I am here, I'm not sure what else to check.

Comment: Best way is to fire a `SQL Server Profiler` and check what query is getting executed. Do check that and let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are missing `@` in following line:-

```
updateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Order", "1");
```

The parameters should exactly match with the query. Also, please read this [blog](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) on "Can we stop using AddWithValue".

Also, you should code with a `using` block to automatically dispose expensive resources. Something like this:-

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strSQLConnectionString)
{
    using(SqlCommand updateCommand = new SqlCommand(strUpdateCommand, connection)
    {
        //Your code goes here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rahul!  Must've looked right over that dozens of times.